# Eclipse plugin working on windows, but not on mac

Tags: eclipse-plugin

My plugin is stored as an archived update site (.zip), and works perfectly fine in Indigo (3.7.1) and Juno (4.2) on Windows. However, when trying to run it on Mac OSX (tried on two different machines) and a fresh Juno, the installation works as usual and the plugin seems to be installed with no errors, but none of the plugin features are available (1 view, 2 buttons on main toolbar).

Starting eclipse from terminal just gives the warning `No binding table for org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialog`, but after a bit of research, this seems to be a known and harmless issue of eclipse 4.2.

When looking at installation details, my plugin is listed as usual, just the features are missing...

What is going on here?

Comment: Is it E4 plugin or "old" plugin with plugin.xml? Is there any logs in the ${install}/configuration? Is there anything on the workspace log?

Comment: It's one with `plugin.xml`. In the configuration directory, there are many files/subdirs, but nothing that looks like a log file...
What exactly is the workspace log, where can I find it? If you mean some console output inside eclipse, there was nothing.

Comment: Workspace log can be found in ${workspace}/.metadata/.log - by default it is outputted to the console as well, but that may be disabled then you'll get an empty console output. Note that by ${workspace} I'm not meaning your primary workspace (the one with your source file) but the workspace of the application you are developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure it out, I did some debugging on a Mac, and it turned out, that it was a problem with the JRE-versions: My plugin requested 1.7, whereas the macs only had 1.6 installed. But still it's strange that eclipse doesn't say a word to the user at any time, even though it's declared in the `MANIFEST.MF`...